# How to add icons to compile py into exe using GitHub Actions?

Tags: python, github-actions

The ico set when I use the Action in GitHub to compile the exe file does not take effect.

Here are my .yml and project structure:

[image: structure]

```yaml
name: 自动编译exe

    on:
      workflow_dispatch:
    
    permissions:
      contents: read
    
    jobs:
      pyinstaller-build:
        runs-on: windows-latest
        steps:
          - name: Set up Python
            uses: actions/setup-python@v2
            with:
              python-version: '3.12'
          - name: Install Dependencies
            run: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip3 install google-generativeai
          - name: Create Executable
            uses: sayyid5416/pyinstaller@v1
            with:
              python_ver: '3.12'
              spec: 'Gemini.py'
              upload_exe_with_name: 'Gemini'
              options: '--onefile --name "Gemini" --windowed --icon gemini.ico'
```